# css pseudo :active => stop propagation

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

i have 2 element: `.parentElement` & `.childElement`.
Both are implement `:active` for making appeared darker when pressed.
The `.childElement` is inside the `.parentElement`.

I want to make `.parentElement:active` not triggered when `.childElement:active` triggered.

In javascript it can be done by using `.stopPropagation()`. How about in css way?

Here the project i'm working on:
Each heading are clickable, including the sub-heading.
Basically it's a button inside a button.
When a user click on it, the page will scroll to corresponding section.
[image]

Comment: It's a bit easier for people to help if you could include a working example, HTML and CSS as a Stackoverflow snippet, use the <> button when you edit to add the code.

Comment: see the screenshot above, i've updated the post

Comment: Please include your Code (HTML/CSS/JS).

Comment: it's part of my whole react project, the css are generated by several js files. I've no idea how to merge them into single css/js/html and posted here

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you're asking, but in CSS the parent is active when the child is active - I don't believe there's any way to prevent the click from "bubbling".
Instead you could fake it, by using sibling elements that you've styled to appear nested, as follows:

```
<style>
    .parentElement {background-color:#ff9999;padding:8px;}
    .childElement {background-color:#9999ff;border:solid 8px #ff9999;border-top-width:0;padding:8px;}

    .parentElement:active {background-color:#ff3333;}
    .parentElement:active ~ .childElement {border-color:#ff3333;}
    .childElement:active {background-color:#3333ff;}
</style>

<div class="parentElement">Parent</div>
<div class="childElement">First child</div>
<div class="childElement">Second child</div>
<div class="childElement">Third child</div>
```

Please let me know if this helps :-)